# Polymorphism (not) broken with visitor pattern in C# (and new instead of override)

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overriding, visitor-pattern

I have the following code:

```
class Visitor 
{
    internal virtual void Visit(Node n) { }
}

class VisitorSpecial : Visitor 
{
    internal new void Visit(Node n) { }
}

class Base
{ 
    internal virtual void Accept(Visitor v) { }
    internal virtual void Accept(VisitorSpecial v) { }
}

class Node : Base
{
    internal override void Accept(Visitor v){ v.Visit(this); }
    internal override void Accept(VisitorSpecial v){ v.Visit(this); }
}
```

Is there any reason why the
 `Accept(Visitor v)` 
method would be chosen when calling
 `new Node().Accept(new VisitorSpecial())`

Update: OK, my bad, I realized I was using "new" in the visitor instead of override. Now I know why "new breaks polymorphism". This makes my question totally stupid. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hmm. I only hava a Mono C# Compiler at hand, but on my box the correct Accept(VisitorApecial v) is choosen.

Comment: Shouldn't you add the C# tag to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you ask the question for a specific language (C#?).  It's up to the language to select the most appropriate overload (note: not override!) given an argument.  That depends on the **type of function lookup** it uses: static (compile-time) or dynamic (run-time).

In case your language uses **static binding**, it will probably choose the most specific call, in this case, `n.Accept( new VisitorSpecial() )` would call the second overload.  However,

```
Visitor v = new VisitorSpecial();
n.Accept( v );
```

would be statically bound to the `Node::Accept( Visitor )` function.

In case the language uses **dynamic binding**, it can choose the called function based on the actual runtime type of the argument.

In general, you can **work around** the problem altogether by not using overloading, which is merely syntactic sugar: make a distinction between `AcceptVisitor` and `AcceptSpecialVisitor`.  Add an `AcceptManager` and `AcceptJustSimplyMy` too.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why it would be chosen (it could literally be because it is first in the class declaration and matches the argument provided), but the

```
Accept(VisitorSpecial v)
```

functions are pointless in this situation and seems to be down to a misunderstanding of polymorphism. Try the following to see why:

```
class Visitor 
{
    internal virtual void Visit(Node n) { Console.WriteLine("In normal visitor"); }
}

class VisitorSpecial : Visitor 
{
    internal override void Visit(Node n) { Console.WriteLine("In special visitor"); }
}

class Base
{ 
    internal virtual void Accept(Visitor v) { }
}

class Node : Base
{
    internal override void Accept(Visitor v){ v.Visit(this); }
}
```

With the above, calling

```
someNode.Accept(new VisitorSpecial());
```

will produce the output

```
> In special visitor
```